# basic webscraper not exiting async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, async-await

When I run this function I get the expected result via console.log, but the function is not exited. Why is that the case?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scrape(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const target = await page.goto(url);
    const waiting = await page.waitForXPath('XPATH...');
    const [el] = await page.$x('XPATH...');
    const txt = await el.getProperty('textContent');

    const rawTxt  = txt.jsonValue();
    console.log(rawTxt);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*the function is not exited*"? What did you expect to happen and what happened instead after you got the log?

Comment: The program seems stuck. Command line doesn't come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to close Puppeteer when you complete your task.

```js
// ... your code
browser.close()
```

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scrape(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const target = await page.goto(url);
    const waiting = await page.waitForXPath('XPATH...');
    const [el] = await page.$x('XPATH...');
    const txt = await el.getProperty('textContent');

    const rawTxt  = txt.jsonValue();
    console.log(rawTxt);

    browser.close() // <--
}
```